# Using Moodle Data Manipulation API

Tags: php, moodle

I am trying out sample queries of the Data Manipulation API for moodle. I have tried out the following query so far

```
<?php
require './config.php';
global $DB;
$user= $DB->get_record_sql('SELECT * FROM {mdl_user} WHERE id=?', array(1));
echo mysql_num_rows($user);

?>
```

I am getting 'Error Reading from Database'. I am using moodle on a local installation. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. I don't think you need to add a prefix to the table, as it is added automatically;
2. `get_records_sql()` return the records as an array of *objects*.

In this case you're getting just one record, so it is a single object.

With the appropriate corrections, this code worked for me:

```
<?php
require './config.php';
global $DB;
$user= $DB->get_record_sql('SELECT * FROM {user} WHERE id=?', array(1));
var_dump($user);
?>
```